# Invoke SSRS Report in PowerShell and Register SSRS-Event Log Entry

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

**Need**: A PowerShell script to call an SSRS report (SSRS 2012) such that the web-call appears as a regular interactive request when viewed in SSRS's ExecutionLog3 (SSRS's log DB view).

**Problem**: I've tinkered around w/ the following script to try to figure out what parameters are necessary to force the SSRS server to log the call as if it was coming from a human/browser.  This script works fine.  I'm connected & getting a response for all 3 methods, but SSRS isn't logging it at all.  Were I to invoke the same report in IE/Chrome manually - SSRS logs it accordingly & correctly.

I've used the F12 tools in Chrome to see if I can find, perhaps, some JS code that is actually doing the log-registration-req, alas - too advanced for me.

Thoughts?

```
    # My AdventureWorks Sales Order Detail (.rpl) requires no parameters.

$RS1 = $null
$RS2 = $null
$RS3 = $null

# Try using the direct URL of the report approach 
$Uri1 = 'http://reportstest.domain.com/home/report/AdventureWorks-Test/Sales%20Orders/Sales%20Order%20Detail.rdl'
# Try using the ReportViewer.aspx followed by path & variables approach
$Uri2 = 'http://reportstest.domain.com/Service/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fAdventureWorks-Test%2fSales+Orders%2fSales+Order+Detail&rc:Command=Render'
# Try using the Service approach
$Uri3 = 'http://reportstest.domain.com/Service?/AdventureWorks-Test%2fSales+Orders%2fSales+Order+Detail'

# Try each Uri to see if we create an entry in SSRS's ExecutionLog3
$RS1 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri1 -UseDefaultCredentials -DisableKeepAlive
$RS2 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri2 -UseDefaultCredentials -DisableKeepAlive
$RS3 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri3 -UseDefaultCredentials -DisableKeepAlive

# See the response for each attempt, check for '200'
$RS1.StatusCode
$RS2.StatusCode
$RS3.StatusCode
```

Comment: It would seem that the 200 response is not really telling the whole story. You may need to take a different approach. See the answer to this question: [SSRS and PowerShell...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740951/ssrs-and-powershell-get-report-as-excel)